# Calling ProductService.Insert during an Async method crashes NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, nopcommerce

I have written a product import plugin that will import 50,000 products from a tab delimited file. It's necessary to do a plugin because I have to download images, parse categories, insert manufacturers, etc.

My plugin works great. It can do 100 products in about 2 minutes. This means it will take about 17 hours to do 50,000 products. I wanted to speed this up by making my product insert method Async. When I go to use the ProductService's Insert method NopCommerce crashes. The file it crashes under is the WebHelper and method GetCurrentIPAddress. For some reason this method is being called right after the dbcontext.SaveChanges method. This is a really weird problem. Here is some sample code and maybe someone that knows the source has an idea of what is going on or how to fix this problem.

My goal is to parse and add several products from the text file at once rather than just doing them one at a time.

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AdminAuthorize]
public ActionResult ImportProducts(ConfigurationModel model)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = Server.MapPath(model.Location);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            _caImportService.ImportProducts(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorNotification("File does not exist");
            return RedirectToAction("ImportProducts");
        }
        SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Catalog.Products.Imported"));
        return RedirectToAction("ImportProducts");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ErrorNotification(exc);
        return RedirectToAction("ImportProducts");
    }
}
```

My Service Class method CAImportService.ImportProducts:

```
public virtual async Task ImportProducts(string fileName)
{
    //Open file and start reading in line by line
    using(var file = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(file);

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            if (csv.GetField("Blocked").ToLower() == "false")
            {
                //Set up general product properties and add product
                //Omitted for brevity
                await Task.Run(() => ImportProduct(name, shortDescription, description, pleaseNote, sku, manufacturerPartNumber,
                stockQuantity, price, oldPrice, weight, length, width, height, closeout, warranty,
                brand, tags, categories, pictures));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Private Method InsertProduct:

```
private void ImportProduct(string name, string shortDescription, string description, string pleaseNote, 
    string sku, string manufacturerPartNumber, int stockQuantity, decimal price, decimal oldPrice, 
    decimal weight, decimal length, decimal width, decimal height, string closeout, string warranty,
    string brand, string tags, string categories, string pictures)
{

        var product = new Product();

        // Omitted Set Up Product Properties

        // Crashes after calling this line upon calling dbcontext.SaveChanges
        _productService.InsertProduct(product);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is due to a missing `await` in your controller. Without this, any `async` methods will resume within an ASP.NET request context for a request that has already completed:

```
[HttpPost]
[AdminAuthorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportProducts(ConfigurationModel model)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = Server.MapPath(model.Location);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            await _caImportService.ImportProducts(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorNotification("File does not exist");
            return RedirectToAction("ImportProducts");
        }
        SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Catalog.Products.Imported"));
        return RedirectToAction("ImportProducts");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ErrorNotification(exc);
        return RedirectToAction("ImportProducts");
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. My performance not increase going from regular to async though

Comment: @DavidGood: How are you measuring performance? `async` on ASP.NET only improves scalability by reducing pressure on the thread pool; it will not magically make an individual request go faster.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what Async does then. I thought it would let me process several lines of the csv file at once rather than just one at a time.